# gcc warnings for no-effect statements.

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

I have a logging macro which in release mode becomes:

```
#define LOG (void)
```

So statement

```
LOG("foobar %d", 0xbabecafe);
```

is expanded to

```
(void)("foobar %d", 0xbabecafe);
```

The problem is that the last expression produces an warning under gcc:

```
warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

How can I change the logging macro such that no warning is issued? (Note, that I don't want to add compiling flag `-Wunused-value`).

**EDIT** I see already a couple of answers involving `(...)`. The same file is compiled under Minix which doesn't support variadic macros. The best would be to have a C89 conforming solution. While your answer is correct (and I upvoted it), it is my fault that I didn't include this small detail.

Comment: A version of gcc that has no variadic macros when compiling C? You surprise me.

Comment: Minix doesn't use gcc. It uses acc which is a minimal C compiler. gcc suports variadic macros alright.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the old school way of dealing with this is to take advantage of double parens. Something like this:

```
LOG(("message: %d", 10));
```

Then for your macro, you define it like this:

```
#define LOG(x) printf x
```

or

```
#define LOG(x) (void)0
```

Because of the double parens, the pre-processor treats the whole inner paren as a single parameter. This at least used to work in visual studio.

**EDIT**: I did a quick test, it works with gcc with -ansi, so it should be good:

`gcc -DNDEBUG -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall test.c -o test`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define LOG(x) printf x
#else
#define LOG(x) (void)0
#endif

int main() {
    LOG(("message: %d\n", 10));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -Wextra is required in the test (to activate -Wunused-value).

Comment: `-W` is equivalent to `-Wextra`. From the gcc manpage: `(This option used to be called -W.  The older name is still supported, but the newer name is more descriptive.)`

Comment: I see, I did't know that. +1 then.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest should be

```
#define LOG(...) (void)0
```

(gcc supports the C99 variadic macros and most other compilers also do these days) That will discard the arguments list, which has two advantages:

- it does not create statements with no effect and
- the arguments are not evaluated at all (if you call non-inline functions in the argument list, in your version the compiler can't eliminate them, while with the variadic macro, the compiler won't see them at all.

Comment: The reason I didn't include `(...)` is that the same file gets compiled under Minix which compiler doesn't support variadic macros.

Comment: @Alexandru: If that compiler does not give you warning, just use a bit of #ifdef magic to give gcc the `LOG(...)` variant and the minix compiler the `LOG` one.

Answer (score 3):

`#define LOG(...)` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For your problems with a non-conforming C implementation (not even C89?) you could do something like

```
static void LOG(char *format, ...) { /* empty */ }
```

even a completely dumb compiler should be able to optimize that out.

Comment: But it will still evaluate the arguments if they involve function calls.

Comment: @JanHudec, yes, you can't have everything. This should be the last resort for non compliant compilers that don't support variadic macros. But according the OP edits, this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I've used

```
#define LOG( t) t
```

for the development version and

```
#define LOG( t)
```

for the release version, with a typical use being

```
LOG( printf( "here\n"));
```